# Pytube module title not giving

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

I am trying to get Youtube video title using `pytube` module
But it giving error . I have tried this code :

```
import pytube
from pytube import YouTube 

video = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Srqs4CitU2U')  

print(video.title)
```

But it Giving Me This Error :

```
PS D:\Programming> & "C:/Users/Offensive Tech/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe" d:/Programming/youtube_video.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Programming\youtube_video.py", line 4, in <module>
    video = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Srqs4CitU2U')  
  File "C:\Users\Offensive Tech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 91, in __init__ 
    self.prefetch()
  File "C:\Users\Offensive Tech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 181, in prefetch
    self.vid_info_raw = request.get(self.vid_info_url)
  File "C:\Users\Offensive Tech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 36, in get       
    return _execute_request(url).read().decode("utf-8")
  File "C:\Users\Offensive Tech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 24, in _execute_request
    return urlopen(request)  # nosec
  File "C:\Users\Offensive Tech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Offensive Tech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\Offensive Tech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\Offensive Tech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 555, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Offensive Tech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Offensive Tech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 747, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Offensive Tech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\Offensive Tech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\Offensive Tech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Offensive Tech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Offensive Tech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 410: Gone
PS D:\Programming>
```

Please tell me the solution that error can solved.

Comment: Please answer the Question ...

Answer (score 1):

You get 410 Error, it's said the page remove from the web. i think is happened because who publish the video remove it from YouTube. I check the code now, and it is work.